# cmake find_package finds the required PKG, but can't show its path

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to retrieve the full path of the ".lib" file I'm linking against.

Tried

```
find_package(PKG 1.0.0 EXACT)
message(STATUS "${PKG_DIR}")
```

and it worked - giving me the `PKGConfig.cmake` file. However, I'm looking for the actual `.lib` file - and I can't find it. `PKG_LIBRARIES` which should have helped me is empty...

The package is another package I build. Could it be missing some definitions in its build / install phase?

Comment: Which package exactly? Every is differnet. `PKGConfig.cmake file` see that file and see what it does.

Comment: it is my internal pkg. It is installed and I can link against it, meaning `find_package` works - I just can't make `cmake` tell me where exactly it is...

Comment: Then show your internal pkg cmake source code. In particular, show PKGConfig.cmake. All `find_package` does is execute `PKGConfig.cmake`. That file can do anything, set any variables.

Comment: Should that file defne those variables? (`PKG_LIBRARIES`, etc.)

Comment: "Should"? Yes, it "should", but there is no police enforcing it. It may do anything, many packages do not set any variables, some set PKG_LIBRARY, there _was_ no standarization. Relevant: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html

Comment: Here is the standarization of variable names https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-stage/manual/cmake-developer.7.html#standard-variable-names